# Is there a granular secured scaffolding solution?

Tags: php, mysql, customization, scaffolding

I'm not entirely sure that this is the Exchange site to post this on, but I haven't seen another that fits.

I am looking for a project which provides scaffolding that supports granular restrictions. I don't need custom labels or anything pretty like that. I have team members who are intelligent enough to add/edit rows in a table, but I cannot let them have access to all tables, or to delete in every table, etc.

What I'm looking for is something like phpMyAdmin, but with the ability to turn off tables, turn off columns in some tables, make some columns read-only, etc. All per user. This would allow me to provide raw db access to different members of my team, without allowing full omnipresent access.

Is there a project which looks to provide this?

Preferably in PHP & mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/en/) and [Adminer Editor](http://www.adminer.org/en/editor/).

They are highly customizable in PHP and they have the additional advantage of being contained in a single PHP file.

If you just want to hide/write-protect some tables and columns, you can always do that in MySQL itself.

Comment: Unless I am missing it, this does not appear to offer ACL granular access restrictions.